# Operand data type varchar is invalid for subtract operator

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to Subtract the datetime type data for example from a column like:

```
         datetime
    20/03/2013:03:17:43
    20/03/2013:03:17:43
    20/03/2013:03:17:44
    20/03/2013:03:17:44
    20/03/2013:03:17:44
    20/03/2013:03:17:44
```

I am using SQL Server R2 2008; with my Query like:

```
    SELECT basescore,

    MAX(datetime) - MIN(datetime)

    FROM log

    GROUP BY basescore
```

But all the time it gives me an error:

```
       Msg 8117, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
       Operand data type varchar is invalid for subtract operator.
```

Can somebody help me solving this error? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are u sure the column of type DateTime?

Comment: Bingo. Use conversion.

Comment: Never store dates as anything other than date or datetime. Never!!!! Don't counpound the problem by casting or converting in the select, fix the data model.

Comment: actually i am importing all data from an excel file so tell me how can i convert the datatype!

Comment: here is the code for converting the datatype: Select convert(DateTime,<ColumnName>) From TableName.

Answer (score 3):

You column is of a VarChar type. Please use conversion in conjunction with DATEDIFF function.

```
SELECT basescore, DATEDIFF(DD,MAX(CAST([datetime] as datetime)), MIN(CAST([datetime] as datetime))) FROM log GROUP BY basescore
```

But I agree - if the column contains datetime data - it should be of a datetime type.

UPDATE: You have a semicolon between date and time. If you do not have control over imported data you can modify the above query as

```
SELECT basescore, DATEDIFF(DD,MAX(CAST(STUFF([datetime],11,1,' ') as datetime)), MIN(CAST(STUFF([datetime],11,1,' ') as datetime))) FROM log GROUP BY basescore
```

But as you see it's getting more and more involved. It would be much easier and safer if the column were of datetime type.

Comment: Are you sure that is necessary once you are using DATEDIFF instead of `-`?  The examples in MSDN documentation seem to suggest it isn't: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx

Comment: it gives me an error "Msg 174, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
The datediff function requires 3 argument(s)"

Comment: @AbeMiessler only for MIN/MAX operators, so they will be performed on correct data type.

Comment: its still giving me the error "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string" lols whats the problem with it I have been trying since last 4hrs lols

Comment: @user2496503 that semicolon between date and time - does it come from your import? If so you have to remove it before CAST would work.

Comment: @user2496503 Updated the answer for case where data imported as it is shown

Comment: still gives error "The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value"

Comment: @user2496503 That's a completely different story. Your date is coming in `dd/mm/yyyy` (British) format. If your SQL Server's Language is different  (e.g. US `mm/dd/yyyy`) it will not be a valid date. You will have to consolidate it somehow - either change the source or change server language or add yet another conversion code that swaps day and month

Answer (score 2):

"Operand data type varchar is invalid for subtract operator" the data type varchar is invalid .. so use CAST to convert data type as datetime

Comment: What did this add over Yurly's answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT basescore,DATEDIFF(DD,MAX(datetime),MIN(datetime))FROM log GROUP BY basescore
```

Answer (score -3):

you have to use datediff function

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258269(v=sql.80).aspx

Thanks

Comment: -1 Please add more than only a link to your answer. This should rather be a comment.